# How can I stick a process to a specific console while having more that one console open?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I am using Eclipse Mars to write test applications. Sometimes I need to run two apps at the same time so I open two consoles on my Eclipse. I can change the process being viewed on one of the consoles, but as soon as the other process prints something, it switches both consoles to show that. How can I stick a process to a specific console?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't assign a process to a console. BUT you can make a process appear on a specific console none the less. To reach that you must click **'Pin Console'** for the program you don't want to be changed on startup. Then in the console of the other program uncheck 'Pin Console'. The next program you start will show up in the unpinned console. So you will have to pin and unpin before each start of either one of your programs.

*Maybe someone else is interested in the other steps besides the pinning and unpinning:*

In the console view uncheck the buttons for

> Show console view when standard out changes

and

> Show console view when standard error changes

then go to the drop down menu of the console view and click

> new console view

then start your first part of the application and assign one of the available consoles to that process and then start the next part and assign that to the other console. You can position both consoles as you are used to with eclipse and watch both of them simultaneously.

[image]

I tested this for eclipse luna and neon (so mars (which is in between) should have the same feature).